# DNS setup for one domain with HTTP on one IP and HTTPS on a second IP

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, a-record

Regarding DNS records, how do I setup one domain, `www.example.com`, which has HTTP for `www` on 1.1.1.1 and HTTPS for `www` on 2.2.2.2?

For clarity:

- HTTP www.example.com resolves to 1.1.1.1
- HTTPS www.example.com resolves to 2.2.2.2

Currently I have:

```
@   IN A 1.1.1.1
www IN A 1.1.1.1
```

My current (average) knowledge of DNS records is suggesting that I'm not going to be able to set it up that way. Instead I'll have to create a new a-record to something like `secure IN A 2.2.2.2`.

Note: Setting HTTPS www.example.com on 1.1.1.1 is not an option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do what you are asking directly unless you want HTTPS traffic to go to e.g. secure.example.com instead of www.example.com.

The only solution would be to put a proxy/firewall/load balancer device in front of your webservers that forwarded on traffic to the different IP addresses based on the protocol used.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to perform this with DNS, as you have to have one IP address for a given NAME, irrespective of the protocol the options available to you are:

- Use a firewall/router to route the traffic accordingly to different servers.
- Add a *new* record for, for example, `secure.example.com` as `2.2.2.2`, configure the server hosting `1.1.1.1` to redirect any HTTPS requests for `www.example.com` to `secure.example.com`